# Use F8 to traverse "Find Symbol" results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've read that's possible (e.g. [here](http://nilsnaegele.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/tip-3-19-how-to-browse-find-symbol-results/) ). But it doesn't work.

It seems to already be set, because in **Tools** -> **Options** -> **(Show all settings)** -> **Environment** -> **Keyboard** -> **Edit.GoToNextLocation** I already have "**F8 (Global)**". But it's not working.

So how do I make it work?

(Do you have it working?)

Answer (score 0):

First, Click to activate the "Find symbol results" tab, then F8 works. When traversing through errors and warnings, pressing F4 works without first having to click on the Build tab. But for some reason, here you should first activate the "Find symbol results" tab.